# How to schedule an enterprise Android app update?

Tags: android

We're working on an enterprise Android (Flutter) app which cannot be interrupted during work hours. The only right time to update it is when it's started. It's not public either so we probably are going to use beta testing mode in Google Play.

Is there any way to schedule the app update so it would execute only when the app is starting?

Comment: I don't think that Play Store allows a sheduled update. The only way would be if the app itself would check for an update at start-up and then download and installs it or opens the Play Store page and tells the user to manually click the upgrade button (assuming the device is not configured to automatically install all app updates without user interaction).

Comment: The first option (download and installs it) is OK, can it be silent or it requires user interaction? I read Play Store docs but couldn't find any way to update an app silently.

Comment: App updates can only be installed silently by system apps (such as Google play services). Your own app will never be able to do so if it is a regular app.